# One button submit, only submitted the last form

Tags: javascript, forms

Two forms exist, it doesn't matter which one is last, always the last one is submitted.

```
<script>
    function submitall()
       {
         document.getElementById("form2").submit();
         document.getElementById("form1").submit();
       }
  </script>
```

Comment: can you provide html code please?

Comment: If the form2 is the last form, then its normal that it submits just the last form, because submit refreshes page so the second one is not fired up.

Comment: Calling `.submit()` reloads the page, so all scripts stop running.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to submit the first form, then submit the second form when the response arrives.

Comment: You can't submit both forms at the same time. Before your browser can redirect you to the `action` of the first form, your seconds form gets submitted.

Comment: AJAX is the only solution to your problem as suggested by @Barmar

Comment: @Barmer, how my ajax post should looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

HTML

These belong to form1

```
<input type="text" id="form11" name="i1" />
<input type="text" id="form12" name="i2" />
```

Let's say this one belonged to form2

```
 <input type="text" id="form21" name="i3" />
```

Javascript should look something like this

```
function ajaxRequest(){
     var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
     if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
      for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
       try{
        return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
       }
       catch(e){
        //suppress error
       }
      }
     }
     else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
      return new XMLHttpRequest()
     else
      return false
    }
var mypostrequest=new ajaxRequest()
mypostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mypostrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mypostrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mypostrequest.responseText // ajax response
  }
  else{
   alert("An error has occured making the request")
  }
 }
}

function submitForm(page,parameters)
           {
  mypostrequest.open("POST", page, true);
  mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  mypostrequest.send(parameters);
           }
var value1=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("form11").value);
var value2=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("form12").value);
var value3=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("form21").value);
var p1="i1="+value1+"&i2="+value2;
var p2="i3="+value3;
var parameters=[p1,p2];               
    var pages = ['basicform1.php','basicform2.php'];
    for(var i=0;i<pages.length;i++)
    {
       submitForm(pages[i],parameters[i]);
    }
```

Comment: As the @Barmar said, he need to use AJAX in order to do it. When he uses your script the first form will reload the page now.

Comment: @Redrif how the Ajax post should be looks like?

Comment: Provide the html code so i can put an answer. Are you already using jquery or do you want pure javscript solution?

Comment: @Amir Also when you will update the question with html code, tell me what you want to do with the submitted form.

Comment: I think something like this is what you need @Amir